# Python read table from html file and write to multiple csv files

Tags: python, html, python-2.7

Experts
We are running system with python 2.7.5. No pandas and I cant install anything. If I have to upgrade python its a long process and it may or may not happen. With these constraints (if i had pandas, it would have been easy and i tried on my local system but I cant do any installs at all) in mind, I tried to look for pure python code that can read certain tables from html file, produce csv file for each table. Any ideas will be greatly appreciated

Thanks